# Viewing/Recovering pending code reviews in Github

Tags: github, pull-request, github-codereviews

When I start a code review, I can add multiple comments with a 'pending' status review and then submit them all at once instead of one-by-one.

If I close the review and come back to it, those pending comments are saved, but it requires me going back to that same pull request. Is there a way to search specifically for those PRs where I have started a review, but have not submitted yet? I tried using a search for `commenter:me is:open` and `is:pending` but this only returns PRs where I have fully published comments.

Comment: You could try using the "reviewed-by:me" or "review:changes_requested" filters. But they probably wont work, because you didn't submit yet.

Unluckily I don't think there is a way to search for these PRs specifically. 

Here is the link to the documentation about searching issues and PRs anyway:
https://help.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests

Comment: I think you can try this link, it may do the trick:
https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/viewing-a-pull-request-review